# Difference between backend service URL and web service URL in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I noticed there are two places to set the backend URL in Azure APIM:
In the Design tab:

[image]

And in the Settings tab:

[image]

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure API Management - API End-Point Domain vs Actual API URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776117/azure-api-management-api-end-point-domain-vs-actual-api-url)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT it doesn't. That's an old version of the Portal and it doesn't mention the URL that is in the Design tab.

Comment: Hello @DavidKlempfner , If i understand correctly... The URL where your Backend API is hosted is known as the **Web Service URL.** It can be hosted on-premises or in the cloud. Which URL scheme should be used for the transport layer. API management URL suffix - this suffix is applied to the API URL. In API management, this should be unique to the API.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT my question isn't about the URL suffix.

Comment: If we will not add the `web service URL` we will get an error like `http 500` . So the Web service URL is the URL where your Backend API is hosted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though Web service URL and backend service URLs are used interchangeably in many places, below are the major differences:

- Every API has only one Web service URL whereas API can have multiple backend services (One for each operation)
- Web Service URLs are http/https endpoints whereas backend services can be http/https service URLs/Logic Apps/Azure Functions and other Azure service.
- When backend service is not defined explicitly then web service URL is taken by default as backend service. For Ex. web service is 'http://contoso.com/employees' . You have operation '/country' and you haven't used backend service then the resultant backend endpoint for operation will be 'http://contoso.com/employees/country'

In which cases you should be using different backend services. I have used them in below cases:

1. Every operation had a different backend logic app used for data transformation
2. Created a bucket of APIs having different web services. Example - I have Single HR api in which we have 2 operations. 1-hours are fetched from mytime portal and 2-chargeability fetched from the payroll portal. So, in that case we didnt use web service instead defined two different backend services.

Answer (score 0):

- The ***web service URL is the URL where our backend API is hosted*** , If we will not add the web service URL we will get an error as `http 500`
- When we add our `webservice url` while creating an API the Backend http end point will reflect the same.

Here is the screenshot for reference:
[image]
[image]

For more information please refer this [***Blog***](https://carldesouza.com/backend-service-url-is-not-defined-in-azure-app-service/) & ***[MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/backends)***

Comment: But you can change the backend http endpoint to something other than what is in the web service URL. So if the web service URL is where the backend API is hosted, what is the backend http endpoint for?

Comment: Hello @DavidKlempner , Based on the given MS DOC in answer "A backend (or API backend) in API Management is an HTTP service that implements your front-end API and its operations". For more information could you please refer this MS DOC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/transform-api
Thank you.

Comment: In what situation would you want them to be different?